# How to make div fill full height of parent in tailwind

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind in my Vuejs app. I have this simple template

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-gray-500 h-screen">
    <Header /><!-- //height 32 -->
    <div class="w-2/3 mx-auto p-4 text-lg bg-white h-full shadow-lg">
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The div with `h-screen` is the root or my app. The component`<header>` has a tailwind height of `h-32`

The problem is that the second div causes the page to scroll at the bottom, the height of the `<header>` (h-32).

## What I want to do

If there is no content, I want the second div to fill the remaining height of the screen but no more.
If there is content, I want it grow as necessary.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can leverage `.flex`, `.flex-col` and `.flex-1` for this. Check out [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex#flex-1).

```html
<div class="bg-gray-500 flex flex-col h-screen">
  <div class="flex h-32 bg-gray-200"></div>
  <div class="flex-1 w-2/3 mx-auto p-4 text-lg bg-white h-full shadow-lg bg-gray-300">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! ([Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) rightly highlights a css conflict for the use of both `bg-white` and `bg-gray-300`)

Answer (score 13):

Usage of `flex-1` is optimal for your solution to expand a certain component in the parent:

> Use `flex-1` to allow a flex item to grow and shrink as needed, ignoring its initial size:

#### Vertically

```
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="h-50 bg-cyan-400 text-center text-4xl">Header</div>
  <div class="flex-1 bg-yellow-400 text-center text-4xl">I am the body</div>
</div>
```

##### Output:

[image]

---

#### Horizontally

```
<div class="flex w-screen ">
  <div class="h-50 bg-cyan-400 text-center text-4xl">NavBar</div>
  <div class="flex-1 bg-yellow-400 text-center text-4xl">I am the body</div>
</div>
```

##### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a background color that you want to always fill the screen, even when the components don't, you can do:

```xml
<div class="dark">
  <main class="h-full min-h-screen">
  ...
  </main>
</div>
```

That way you always have at "minimum" a full viewport...