# How can I force a child element to take the remaining vertical height within its parent using TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Essentially I just want the div to fill in its available space without creating more.  Here is a picture of what's happening: the blue div is the child the black outline is the parent.
[image: picture]

When I change the min height I to be the screen height I get something else that's also wrong and the div expands past the page (because I assume it buts heads with header):[image: scroll]

Here is the first couple divs with the TailwindCSS options:

```
div className="flex flex-auto justify-center outline h-screen">
            {/* Container for the ticket info and interface */}
            <div className="flex flex-row w-1/2 h-3/4 content-center rounded-lg shadow-lg p-2 m-3 outline outline-blue-300">
                {/* left hand side container that has the status picture and some buttons. */}
                <div className="">
```

I cut it off there because I think I should be able to fix this by just fixing the toplayer divs.

For the record I saw this: [How to make div fill full height of parent in tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412303/how-to-make-div-fill-full-height-of-parent-in-tailwind)

I was already doing what this recommended but it didn't work.

Comment: can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please upload this on CodeSandbox, as well as details more about what you want to do.